# Excel - leave blank if value is 0 but not if value is 0.03

Tags: excel, cells, zero

I'm currently leaving cells blank if the value is 0 by using the following custom format ""#,###;;;@," which works great but how do I change this so that values like "0.03" are not left blank but shown as 0?

I tried several variations but had no luck. Any suggestions?

**SOLUTION**

```
#,##0;;;@
```

Comment: Try changing to `0.00;;;@`.  From what I can tell currently `0` will disappear, while `0.03` will show as `0` (but won't disappear as its actual value is >0).

Comment: I just tried with your format string and the values like 0.03 are not left blank, they turn into 0

Comment: youre right @AndreyBelykh, see update.

Comment: Add the decimal places; `#,##0.00;;;@`

Comment: got it!! it's #,##0;;;@, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

If I caught what you need this is the solution:

```
General;;;@
```

Comment: it was this:  #,##0;;;@

Comment: That will turn `0.03` into `0`. Didn't catch you wanted that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an **Option** for this at the worksheet level:

[image]

Clear that bottom checkbox.